# arm-linux-gcc command not working

Tags: command-line

I have installed the following :

> yum install gcc-arm-linux*

but when i am trying to run the following command:

> ./arm-linux-gcc

it is giving the output as:

> ./arm-linux-gcc: no such file or directory

how can i resolve this? please help

Comment: D'you know what `./` means?

Answer (score 2):

You should type `arm-linux-gcc` instead of `./arm-linux-gcc`.

`./arm-linux-gcc` indicate that you run `arm-linux-gcc` program, located in you current working directory. So the shell can not find you program because it is installed somewhere in your `$PATH`.

You can find its location by using:

```
which arm-linux-gcc
```